# viewing rendered animation from command line

Tags: rendering, animation, command-line

I've looked around online for this but it seems every source I find is dancing around the issue. I've created a build script so far that looks like this

```
  blender oop-blender-demo.blend -P model.py -- $1
  blender oop-blender-demo.blend -a
```

I want to add one more line that allows me to actually view the rendered animation like you can do in the blender app by going to Render --> Play Rendered Animation

Is there anyway to succinctly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Call the operator**

To Play Rendered Animation you call the operator. For example sake saved to a file *`scripts/playback.py`*

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.render.play_rendered_anim()
```

To call the operator from command line

```
blender -P scripts/playback.py tests/demo.blend
```

The operator makes a command based on your ***`User Preferences > Files > Animation Player`***  settings.
[image]

Which in the case for Internal Player will be something like

```
Executing command:
   '/../bin/blender -a -f 24 1.0 -s 0 -e 4 -j 1 /tmp/0000.png'
```

see [blender command line arguments](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#animation-playback-options)

The script that generates the command can be found in ***`2.79/scripts/startup/bl_operators/screen_play_rendered_anim.py`***

Answer (score 1):

```
blender -a -s 1 -e 250 /path_to_rendered_frames/name_of_1st_frame.png
```

Comment: I think this could do with some explanation of how this works.

Comment: I agree but I didn't find any doc about that. I just copied/paste the command that pops in the console when you press "Play Rendered Animation".

Comment: trying to deconstruct this, I believe the 1 is the variable frame_start and 250 is frame_end.

Comment: @thibsert Unfortunately when running this command from command line it does not show the whole animation